# Mensagem de erro se o usuário digitar um caractere diferente

Tags: string, dart

Estou aprendendo um pouco de dart, fiz esse comando para quando o usuário inserir uma letra o programa responda se a letra é uma vogal ou consoante. Está rodando tranquilo.

Mas queria saber como colocar uma mensagem de erro, se o usuário digitar algum número ou outo tipo de caractere.

```
void main() {
  String letra;
  List<String> vogais = ['a','A','e','E','I','i','O','o','U','u']; /// Só declarei a variavel vogal por ter somente 5 valores.
   
  letra = 'A';
  
  if (vogais.contains(letra)){
    print("A letra $letra é uma vogal"); /// Se a letra que eu digitei estiver na lista das vogais,o programa responde que ela é uma vogal
  }
  else {
  print("A letra $letra é uma consoante");
  } /// se não estiver nessa lista, o programa vai tratar a letra como uma consoante
}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Começo pegando apenas o primeiro caractere para garantir que não tem outros sendo avaliados. E comparo só com minúsculo.

Preciso comparar tanto com as vogais quanto com as consoantes para saber se é uma delas ou se não é. Se não for nenhuma das duas, aí sim eu sei que foi passado um valor inválido.

```
import 'dart:io';
 
void main() {
    VogalOuConsoante("A");
    VogalOuConsoante("c");
    VogalOuConsoante("1");
    VogalOuConsoante("Nome");
}

void VogalOuConsoante(String letra) {
    var chr = letra[0].toLowerCase();
    if ("aeiou".contains(chr)) {
        print("A letra ${letra[0]} é uma vogal");
    } else if ("bcdfghjklmnpqrstuvxyz".contains(chr)) {
        print("A letra ${letra[0]} é uma consoante");
    } else {
        print("${letra[0]} não é uma letra");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/bhzOoq). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/xobzmziuhn-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Dart/VowelOrConsonant.dt).